# Deep copy an abstract class in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, class, copy

I have the following class I want to copy:

```
abstract class AbstractEnvironment : Environment {}
```

I tried doing it with the built in Kotlin copy() method like this:

```
class Test(
    val env: AbstractEnvironment
) {
    private var envCopy: AbstractEnvironment = env.copy()
```

Which does not work since the copy method works solely for data classes.
The Environment class needs to stay abstract for my appliance.

How can I perform a deep copy instead?

Comment: Each concrete subclass of AbstractEnvironment will need to provide its own `copy` method, because each of them may have specific properties that need to be copied, and only the subclasses know how to. You can provide an abstract function `copy` and override it in your subclasses. You will have to do it manually because they're not data classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For instance, you can create a function within the AbstractEnvironment to perform a deep copy of its properties:

```
abstract class AbstractEnvironment : Environment {
    abstract fun copy(): AbstractEnvironment // Abstract method for deep copy
}

class Test(val env: AbstractEnvironment) {
    private var envCopy: AbstractEnvironment = env.copy()

    // Function to perform deep copy
    private fun deepCopyEnvironment(original: AbstractEnvironment): AbstractEnvironment {
        // Implement deep copy logic here
        // Create a new instance of AbstractEnvironment and copy its properties

        // For example:
        val copy = object : AbstractEnvironment() {
            // Override necessary methods/properties and copy their values
            // Example:
            override fun someMethod() {
                // Copy method implementation
            }
        }

        // Copy other properties as needed
        // copy.property = original.property

        return copy
    }

    init {
        envCopy = deepCopyEnvironment(env)
    }
}
```

This approach involves creating a function deepCopyEnvironment that manually constructs a new instance of AbstractEnvironment and copies its properties as needed. You'll need to override abstract methods or properties in the anonymous class used for copying.